# Как в java удалять часть строки?

Tags: java, строки

Допустим у меня есть строка `String s = "У лукоморья дуб зелёный";`
Как мне сделать так, чтобы программа находила и удаляла, к примеру слово "дуб", если оно есть в строке, оставляя при этом остальные части строки не тронутыми?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [`replace()`](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/replace-v-java/). Он меняет один кусок строки на другую строку. В вашем случае можно менять "дуб" на пустой символ.

```
String str = "У лукоморья дуб зелёный";
System.out.println(str.replace("дуб", ""));
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694984/remove-part-of-string-in-java/8695026#8695026)

Comment: проблема в том, что сама-то строка не изменяется.

Comment: @michael_best почему?

Comment: @michael_best String это immutable класс. При вызове replace метода создается другая строка.

Comment: @tsyklop я это знаю, но этого, как мне кажется, и не хватает в ответе

Comment: @michael_best почему? Переменная изменяется - изменяется. Зачем указывать информацию про то, как устроен String внутри? Тогда в каждом ответе, связанным с изменением переменной String, стоит указывать эту информацию.

Comment: @michael_best сама строка, хранящаяся в переменной не изменяется, а переменная - изменяется. В контексте этого вопроса никому никакого дела до строки нет